# What is the use of the LIST privilege in IBM netezza

Tags: privileges, netezza

In a Netezza database, what exactly does the 'LIST' privilege do? I understand what a 'SELECT' privilege does, but what does 'LIST' allow a user to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIST is an object privilege, and is required to see the object (usually the object's name in a list).

SELECT object privilege does implicitly grant LIST, so you can always see a table that you can SELECT from, but LIST doesn't imply SELECT.

You can find information on [Netezza object privileges here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_object_privs.html).

Comment: Thanks, if someone gets SELECT privilege, does it not automatically allow them to see it? OR we need to explicitly GRANT 'LIST'?

Comment: Ah, yes! Updated answer